# Facebook Open Graph Protocol - pages created for admin to manage

Tags: php, facebook, admin, facebook-opengraph

I have a website with like 50-60 dynamically generated pages, where I implemented the like button along with open graph protocol (ogp).

I want to manage this pages like a regular facebook page and post to my fans, for that I have specificed myself as page admin in the meta tags and liked my posts but I can't find this page in my manage pages section.

I tested my website by adding/removing different meta tags to make it working and tested it on facebook linter tool. Somehow I got two pages in the manage pages section but the remaining are not working.

You can view my website here:
http://freshlylike.com/view.php?id=404

Please help.

Thanks,
happyhardik

Answer (score 0):

That's because in order to see those pages in you Manage Pages section, the admin listed in the open graph tag has to actually click the link - according to Facebook

> Each listed user must click Like on
>   the URL to be approved as an admin.
>   This is to prevent users being made
>   admins without their consent.

I encountered the same problem too, so might have to work around that.

Comment: I did click on a lot of posts, but it doesn't work. Did "Like"/"Unlike" many times, no use.